# django + ajax - поиск лучшего подхода

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

Добрый день. 
Есть простой тестовый проект на Django. Меню из трех страниц, на каждой - текст.

Задача: переходить между страницами без перезагрузки страницы.

Читая решения и все, что связано со связкой "django+ajax", понимаю, что имею большое число белых пятен в понимании как **это** должно работать. Большинство ответов и гайдов, которые я встречал, предлагают использование этой функции:

```
render_to_string
```

Читая [доки](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/templates/#django.template.loader.render_to_string), не понятно что передавать в "context".

Кроме этого кто-то советует копать в сторону JsonResponse, кто-то в Dajax и пр.

На данный момент имею решение, которое не работает. При переходе на другую страницу - происходит два запроса, вместо одного. Рушится структура DOM-дерева (в контейнер главного html-документа, где должен заменяться сугубо текст, вставляется другой полноценный html-документ).

Код, на примере одной из страниц (они одинаковы).

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', real_home, name='real-home'),
url(r'^home', home, name='home'),
url(r'^first', first_page, name='first'),
url(r'^second/', second_page, name='second'),]
```

view.py:

```
def first_page(request):
context = {
    "title": "First Page",
}
return render(request, "first.html", context,)
```

base.html (сокращенный):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<li><a href="#" class="class_first"> First page</li> </a>
 <div class='container'>
   {% block content %}
   {% endblock content %}
 </div>
 <script >
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $(".class_home").click(function(){
        $.ajax({url: "/home", success: function(result){
          $(".container").html(result);
        $(".container").fadeOut(0).fadeIn(1000);
          console.log(result);
 </script>
```

first.html

```
{% block head_title %}
{{ title }} | {{ block.super }}
{% endblock head_title %}
{% block content%}
<center><h1>First page CONTENT</h1></center>
<br>
<p>Content text</p>
{% endblock content%}
```

До дыр перечитав руководства и слоняясь из тупика в тупик, прошу совета у сообщества напрямую.

**Как оно должно работать? Что мне стоит использовать?**

Буду благодарен за любые мысли на этот счет.

Comment: Попробуйте для начала:
1. для каждой страницы сделать шаблон без наследования и написать там текст
2. Проще использовать будет JsonResponse(по опыту)
3. render_to_string(название темлейта, контекст - словарь данных которые будут использоваться в темлейте)
4. JsonResponse вызовите например ({'content': render_to_response(template_name, {})}

Comment: @ivanK. оформите пожалуйста свой комментарий как ответ

Answer (score 3):

В одном из своих проектов я использовал что-то похожее, пример который я приведу ниже - проще вашего вопроса, но содержит всю необходимую информацию.

views.py

```
def ajax(request):
    return HttpResponse('<p>Here will be your HTML page</p>')
```

index.html - пример страницы и клавиш (упрощенный)

```
<div id="demo">
    <button type="button" class="class_home">Change Content</button>
    </div>
    <div id="div1"></div>
    <script src="https://yastatic.net/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script >
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".class_home").click(function(){
          $.ajax({url: "ajax_url", success: function(result){
            $("#div1").html(result);
            console.log(result);
          }});
        });
    });
    </script> 
    </body>
    </html>
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('ajax_url', views.ajax, name='ajax'),
]
```

В примере выше - мы запрашиваем кусочек html, и вставляем его внутрь div1.
Всех благ, если есть вопросы - отвечу.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте для начала:

1. Элемент списка
2. для каждой страницы сделать шаблон без наследования и написать там текст
3. Проще использовать будет `JsonResponse`(по опыту)
4. `render_to_string`(название темлейта, контекст - словарь данных которые будут использоваться в темлейте)
5. `JsonResponse` вызовите например ({'content': render_to_response(template_name, {})}

Answer (score 1):

> в контейнер главного html-документа, где должен заменяться сугубо
> текст, вставляется другой полноценный html-документ

Как бы банально это не звучало но это по тому что вы возвращаете браузеру html документ и вставляете этот документ в другой документ.

Добавьте в view.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
```

Замените:

```
return render(request, "first.html", context,)
```

на

```
return HttpResponse("title: First Page")
```

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, что подобную задачу легко реализовать, если включить кусочек JavaScript, который умеет изменять содержимое HTML без перезагрузки страницы.

Первый же пример, по-моему, подходит:

[JavaScript Can Change HTML Content](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_intro.asp).

Comment: Приведите пример в текстовом виде, а не по ссылке, чтобы при инвалидации ссылки ответ сохранил смысл

Comment: _Подробнее не могу сказать - мой аналогичный вопрос еще впереди_, ну так  лучше сначала задать вопрос, а потом дать ответ.